# checkbox in listview to select and delete

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-checkbox

This is my code I have one list view in the fragment which read sms using cursor I have set check box in adapter and I have 3 buttons outside the list view in main layout I need the followings

1.When I click one button it display checkbox in the list

2.when I select and scroll the list selected items wont disappears

3.select all button to select all in the list 4.delete button to delete the selected item remaining messages instantly updated.

```
     public class TabFragment extends Fragment 
     {

      ListView mlistView;

ArrayList<Message> sms = new ArrayList<Message>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sms, container, false);
    mlistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
    Button sdel=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sdelete);
    populateMessageList();
    sdel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    return view;

}

public void populateMessageList() {
    fetchInboxMessages();

    if (fetchInboxMessages() != null) {

        mlistView.setAdapter(new datalist(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),this));
    }

}



public ArrayList<Message> fetchInboxMessages() {

    Uri muriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor mcursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(muriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" }, null, null,
            null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {

        Message mMessage = new Message();
        mMessage.setmAddress(mcursor.getString(mcursor
                .getColumnIndex("address")));
        mMessage.setmBody(mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
        mMessage.setmDate(mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("date")));

        sms.add(mMessage);

    }

    return sms;

}
class datalist extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    Boolean selected;
    Boolean[] checkboxstate;
    public datalist(Context applicationContext, TabFragment tabFragment) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext);
   }  public datalist(Context applicationContext, int simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ArrayList<Message> sms) {



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return sms.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_adapter, parent, false);
        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
         CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);


        Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(sms.get(position).getmDate());
        Calendar mcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mcalendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        DateFormat mformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        txt1.setText(sms.get(position).getmBody());
        txt2.setText("Sent by" + sms.get(position).getmAddress() + "\n" + mformatter.format(mcalendar.getTime()));
   /*     if(selected==false)
        cb.setVisibility(row.GONE);
        else*/
        cb.setVisibility(row.VISIBLE);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sms.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
                if(isChecked){
                 buttonView.setSelected(true);


                    }else {

                buttonView.setSelected(false);
                }

            }
        });



        return row;
    }

}
public class Message {

    private String mAddress;
    private String mBody;
    private String mDate;
    private int icon;
    boolean     selected;

    public void setmAddress(String mAddress) {
        this.mAddress = mAddress;
    }


    public void setmBody(String mBody) {
        this.mBody = mBody;
    }


    public void setmDate(String mDate) {
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }


    public String getmBody() {
        return mBody;
    }

    public String getmAddress() {
        return mAddress;
    }

    public String getmDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
   public int getIcon(){
   return icon;}  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
 }}}
```

Comment: edited code mr @Er.arjun saini what changes u have made

Comment: used the Viewholder.....for holding the value

Comment: i am using holder now have u put code for removing item in listview

Comment: is anybody here to help me i almost complete now i need to get position to delete suggest some solutions